# controller redirect url with language

Tags: magento-1.9, redirect-url

I have a multi language web, and I need to redirect from the controller to the actual language of the web.

So `$this->_redirectURL('/foo/');` now is redirecting to `example.com/foo/` but I need to redirect to `example.com/en/foo/`

How to introduce the code language in the url redirection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$url = Mage::getUrl('', array('_direct'=>'foo'));
$this->_redirectUrl($url);
```